# Split string using word but keep the word in each array index

Tags: java, regex, string, split

The following code,

```
            String string = "<xml attributes>some xml code</xml>"
                            + "<xml attributes>some xml code</xml>"
                            + "<xml attributes>some xml code</xml>"
                            + "<xml attributes>some xml code</xml>";

            String[] stringArray = string.split("<xml");

            for ( String i : stringArray) {

                System.out.println(i);
            }
```

Prints

```
 attributes>some xml code</xml>
 attributes>some xml code</xml>
 attributes>some xml code</xml>
 attributes>some xml code</xml>
```

But I want to keep the <**xml** word in each of the array indexes so the output would be,

```
 <xml attributes>some xml code</xml>
 <xml attributes>some xml code</xml>
 <xml attributes>some xml code</xml>
 <xml attributes>some xml code</xml>
```

Comment: Every element in array had the `pattern` before it, hence the split. Why don't you just add it. `Pattern + element[i]`.

Comment: seems like a job for an XML parser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your code a little to use positive lookbehind.

`String[] stringArray = string.split("(?<=</xml>)");`

O/P :

```
<xml attributes>some xml code</xml>
<xml attributes>some xml code</xml>
<xml attributes>some xml code</xml>
<xml attributes>some xml code</xml>
```

Comment: Very elegant, indeed!

Comment: @TheLostMind this is what I was looking for but I'm very curious what is the efficiency of this method compared to other techniques and options? I've heard a lot about Tokenizers?

Comment: @Mr.Tea - Well.. This will not be *very inefficient*. This code will indeed look at each character and check whether it is preceded by `</xml>`. Unless the input size is huge, I wouldn't worry about efficiency much.

Answer (score 2):

I can only think of the brute force way of doing this:

```
String string = "<xml attributes>some xml code</xml>"
            + "<xml attributes>some xml code</xml>"
            + "<xml attributes>some xml code</xml>"
            + "<xml attributes>some xml code</xml>";

    String[] stringArray = string.split("<xml");

    for (int i = 1; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
        stringArray[i] = "<xml"+stringArray[i];
    }
    for ( String i : stringArray) {

        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

Note that a for `(String element : stringArray)` will not work here because it copies the element by value, not the pointer to the element in the array.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
        String string = "<xml attributes>some xml code</xml>"
                        + "<xml attributes>some xml code</xml>"
                        + "<xml attributes>some xml code</xml>"
                        + "<xml attributes>some xml code</xml>";

        String strPattern = "<xml";
        String[] stringArray = string.split(strPattern);

        for ( String i : stringArray) {

            System.out.println(strPattern + i);
        }
```

Comment: @K139 sort-of beat me too it, but I posted nonetheless.